# Get part of a value from localStorage - Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, local-storage

so i have an interface callled UserData that contains 4 things: name, shortname, groups & profile.

Although, i just wanna get a portion of UserData, not the whole thing, i just want the profile value; he's a screenshot of how's my key/value relation into localStorage:

[image]

I'm getting UserData like this:
**var busca = localStorage.getItem('userData');**

But this is going to get the whole thing, i just want the **profile** 'RENDA_FIXA'

I can't share the whole code here due to security matters, it's from work.

Well, someone knows how to pick a partial value of this UserData key, and not the whole value?
Would something like: "var busca = localStorage.getItem('userData.profile');" works?

Appreciate it, best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `JSON.parse` to convert it into an object first, before destructuring it:

```
const { profile } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'))
```

Answer (score 1):

while assigning you can decide which property to assign because localstorage can only access on the basis of key i.e. userData. For eg:-

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'))['profile']
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

> The keys and the values are always in the UTF-16 `DOMString` format,
>   which uses two bytes per character.  (As with objects, integer keys
>   are automatically converted to strings.)

So partial retrieval isn't possible from the [`Storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) interface. You need to retrieve the *complete* value (string) first, parse it with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and access the required property.